# Zero product of commuting linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Suppose $T_1,\ldots,T_{n+1}$ are pairwise commuting linear operators
>   on an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$. Suppose $$T_1T_2\ldots
>  T_{n+1}=0$$ Prove that in the above equation at least one of the
>   factors can be removed without changing its validity.

What I can say so far is only that $T_1\ldots T_n=0$ implies that there exists $i\in \{1,\ldots,n+1\}$ such that $\mbox{Im}(T_{j+1})\subset\mbox{Ker}(T_j)$. However, I can't see how I'm supposed to use the fact that linear operators commute -- if they were diagonalizable, then I could say that they are simultaneously diagonalizable, but diagonalizability is nowhere mentioned.

I ran out of ideas. Any hints how to approach this problem?

Comment: Your conclusion is wrong, let $T_{xy}$, $T_{xz}$ and $T_{yz}$ be the orthogonal projections onto the $xy$-, $xz$- and $yz$-plane in $\Bbb R^3$, respectively. Note that $T_{xy} T_{xz} T_{yz} = 0$ but none of the projections kernels contain another projections image.

Comment: @Christoph OP is considering $n+1$ transformations on an $n-$ dimensional space. Your example has only three transformations on a three dimensional space.

Comment: Feel free to add the identity

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are commuting linear operators, then $A(\mathrm{Im}(B)) \subseteq \mathrm{Im}(B)$. So by picking the image of any of those operators there, and restricting the operators to that image, you get a similar equation on a space of potentially smaller dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\Im{Im}$Consider the flag of subspaces
$$0=U_0⊆U_2⊆⋯⊆U_{n+1}=V,$$
where $U_i=\Im(T_{i+1}T_{i+2}⋯T_{n+1})$ for $i=0,…,n$.

This is a flag since $T_{i+1}$ commutes with $T_{i+2}\cdots T_{n+1}$ so that
\begin{align}
U_i &= \Im(T_{i+1}T_{i+2}⋯T_{n+1}) 
\\&= \Im(T_{i+2}⋯T_{n+1}T_{i+1}) \subseteq \Im(T_{i+2}⋯T_{n+1}) = U_{i+1}.
\end{align}

Note that we have
$$U_i=T_{i+1}(U_{i+1}) \qquad\text{for $i=0,…,n$.}$$

Let us denote by $r_i=\dim(U_i)=\operatorname{rank}(T_{i+1}T_{i+2}⋯T_{n+1})$ the dimensions of the subspaces, then we get a weakly increasing sequence of integers
$$0=r_0≤r_1≤⋯≤r_n≤r_{n+1}=n.$$
Hence, there must be an index $k≤n$ such that $r_k=r_{k+1}$. But this means that $U_k=U_{k+1}$ so that
\begin{align}
0&=U_0=T_1T_2⋯T_k(U_k)
\\&=T_1T_2⋯T_k(U_{k+1})
\\&=T_1T_2⋯T_kT_{k+2}⋯T_{n+1}(V).
\end{align}

Hence, we may conclude that
$$T_1T_2⋯T_kT_{k+2}⋯T_{n+1}=0.$$

Comment: Thank you for posting the solution. Some questions still remain. What is $U_{n+1}$ and why $U_{n+1}=V$? It should be $U_{n+1}=\mbox{Im}(T_{i+2}...T_{i+1})$ from your definition, but that doesn't make any sense. Why can we say that $\mbox{Im}(T_{i+2}\ldots T_{n+1}T_{i+1})\subseteq\mbox{Im}(T_{i+2}\ldots T_{n+1})$?

Comment: $U_{n+1}=V$ by definition. You can also think of it as the image of the product of *none* of the $T_i$, where the empty product of operators is $\operatorname{id}_V$. Furthermore $\operatorname{Im}(f\circ g) \subseteq \operatorname{Im}(f)$ since the first contains elements of the form $f(g(x))$ while the second contains all elements of the form $f(y)$, so $y=g(x)$ yields the inclusion.

Comment: Just to clarify -- am I right that the last two equations have a typo that should be $\cdots T_k T_{k+2}\cdots$?

Comment: @Hasek Yes indeed, I fixed it. Thanks!